# Codeigniter show private message in view issue?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**What I am trying to accomplish:** I am trying to show a correspondence messages between users.

**What I have so far:**

**Controller:**

```
public function view()
{

     $thread_id = $this->uri->segment(4);


        $this->data['reply'] =  $this->enquire_m->get_messages($thread_id);
}
```

**Model:**

```
 public function get_messages($thread_id='')
     {
        $this->load->model('user_m');
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $query_str = $this->db->query('SELECT *
                                FROM message_replies
                                WHERE message_replies.thread_id = $thread_id');
        $result = $this->db->query($query_str); 
        return $result;

        $this->db->trans_complete();
      }
```

**View:**

```
  <ul>
            <?php  
            $received_message = $this->enquire_m->get_messages();

            foreach ($received_message->result() as $reply) 
            {

              '<li>
             <div class="message-bubble">
             <span class="bubble-user">'.$reply->name_surname.'</span>
              <div class="bubble_left palette palette-clouds" data-domelement="" style="display: block;">
              '.$reply->message.'
              <div class="bubble_arrow"></div>

                              </div>
              <span class="bubble-date">'.$reply->date;
            }

              ?>
             </ul>
```

**DB:**

```
    thread_id           int(11) NOT NULL,
id                  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sender_id          int(11) NOT NULL,
recepient_id       int(11) NOT NULL,
name_surname       varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
date               datetime DEFAULT NULL,
message            text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
readed             binary(1) DEFAULT '0',
```

**URL**

```
index.php/admin/enquire/view/19
```

**The problem:** Nothing is displayed. I get an error on the View it gives me fatal error in

```
foreach ($received_message->result() as $reply)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see what's wrong and I hope somebody can give me a solution.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: WHat is your view name??

Comment: It's "view.php" located in "enquire" folder. I dnt think the problem is with the file name...

Comment: No need to load `user_m` in that method of `enquire_m` - you are not using it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems.

- You are not sending data to a view
- You are not echoing out html.
- You are trying to get data from the model inside your view

You have to remember that a controllers method job is to be the middle man. It will get data from the model and send it to your view. Your view can then render that data as needed

In your case, your controller needs to pass that data like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function view() {
     $thread_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
     $this->data['replies'] =  $this->enquire_m->get_messages($thread_id);
     $this->load->view('enquire/view', $this->data);
}
```

Then in your **View**:

```
<ul>
    <?php  
    //$replies   is the variable sent by the controller
    foreach ($replies as $reply) {
        echo '<li>
                 <div class="message-bubble">
                     <span class="bubble-user">'.$reply->name_surname.'</span>
                     <div class="bubble_left palette palette-clouds" data-domelement="" style="display: block;">
                         '.$reply->message.'
                         <div class="bubble_arrow"></div>
                     </div>
                     <span class="bubble-date">'.$reply->date;
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I would output HTML this way in my view:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($replies as $reply) { ?>
        <li>
            <div class="message-bubble">
                <span class="bubble-user"><?php echo $reply->name_surname ?></span>
                <div class="bubble_left palette palette-clouds" data-domelement="" style="display: block;">
                    <?php echo $reply->message ?>
                    <div class="bubble_arrow"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="bubble-date"><?php echo $reply->date ?>
    <?php } ?> 
</ul>
```

Also, I notice your HTML does not have the proper closing `</div>` make sure you correct that.

Comment: CodeGodie Thank you for your efforts! I managed to get it working using the code you've provided.